# Simple highscore using preferences (Lua - Corona SDK)

Tags: mobile, lua, coronasdk, preferences

And thanks in advance for your help!

I'm trying to implement in my game an highscore feature using "preferences" in Lua, but i'm missing something, here's my code:

```
local highscore_letta = system.getPreference( "app", "highscore", "number" )

-- if preference do not exist, create it and set it to 0 (first time playing the game)
if (highscore_letta == nil) then
    local appPreferences =
    {
        highscore = "0"
    }
    system.setPreferences( "app", appPreferences )
end

-- if the score is higher than current highscore, update it with the new one
if (_G.player_score > highscore_letta) then
    local appPreferences =
    {
        highscore = _G.player_score
    }
    system.setPreferences( "app", appPreferences )
end
```

After the player lose for the first time, the game crashes saying that it's comparing a null value in "highscore_letta".
After a second try, the game do not crashes, but it sticks with 0 and never update it at all.

Any advice? I can't figure out what i'm missing.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
local highscore_letta = system.getPreference( "app", "highscore", "number" ) or 0

-- if the score is higher than current highscore, update it with the new one
if (_G.player_score > highscore_letta) then
    local appPreferences =
    {
        highscore = _G.player_score
    }
    system.setPreferences( "app", appPreferences )
end
```

Comment: Same issue.
Before using preferences I coded the same process but using a "data.sav" file, and everything worked fine, but in some smartphone the game kept crashing because it wasn't able to find the "data.sav" file, that's why i'm trying to use preferences.
I'm really confused.

Comment: Should work. Print out variables to make sure they have proper values. Try use [Simple-Table-Load-Save-Functions-for-Corona-SDK](https://github.com/robmiracle/Simple-Table-Load-Save-Functions-for-Corona-SDK).

Comment: If i print their values in the console i get the same values on screen.
I tried changing the code like this: https://pastebin.com/eGiYvHNg
Now the highscore is stuck on 3900 and don't update, even if I beat it. I also tried the examples given by CoronaSDK and used the SAME code, the problem is still there.
What can be wrong? Maybe some issue by changing scene? This things is driving me crazy.

Comment: May be try read preferences on application start and save it on exit as [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/setPreferences.html) suggest. In mid-time use simple table to store and update data.

Comment: Same issue.
I tried putting this into "main.lua" -> https://pastebin.com/PEBAtULE

and putting this into "game_over.lua" -> https://pastebin.com/Sbdwi9Si

Still remain that "3900" even if I beat it.